# Undefined reference to tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base

Tags: tbb, concurrent-vector

I'm trying to learn how tbb::concurrent_vector works. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I have installed it through ubuntu package.

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev
```

when I try to compile this simple C++ program

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    tbb::concurrent_vector<int> cv ={1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
mmk@mmk:~/my-computer/codes$ g++ main.cpp -o main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPLqyKd.o: in function `tbb::concurrent_vector<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::concurrent_vector(std::initializer_list<int>, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEEC2ESt16initializer_listIiERKS2_[_ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEEC5ESt16initializer_listIiERKS2_]+0xd3): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::internal_clear(void (*)(void*, unsigned long))'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEEC2ESt16initializer_listIiERKS2_[_ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEEC5ESt16initializer_listIiERKS2_]+0x10a): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::~concurrent_vector_base_v3()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPLqyKd.o: in function `tbb::concurrent_vector<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::~concurrent_vector()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED2Ev[_ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED5Ev]+0x4b): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::internal_clear(void (*)(void*, unsigned long))'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED2Ev[_ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEED5Ev]+0x71): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::~concurrent_vector_base_v3()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPLqyKd.o: in function `void tbb::concurrent_vector<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> >::internal_assign_iterators<int const*>(int const*, int const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE25internal_assign_iteratorsIPKiEEvT_S7_[_ZN3tbb17concurrent_vectorIiNS_23cache_aligned_allocatorIiEEE25internal_assign_iteratorsIPKiEEvT_S7_]+0x74): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v3::internal_reserve(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPLqyKd.o: in function `tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb23cache_aligned_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN3tbb23cache_aligned_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x29): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPLqyKd.o: in function `tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb23cache_aligned_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[_ZN3tbb23cache_aligned_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim]+0x20): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::NFS_Free(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have also tried to declared it in these way and failed:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2};
tbb::concurrent_vector cv(v.begin(), v.end);
```

```cpp
tbb::concurrent_vector<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int>> cv;
```

Please tell me how can I encounter this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors because your code is unable to link with the TBB library.

"-ltbb" this flag is used to link with TBB library files

Please try compiling your code with the below command

```
g++ main.cpp -ltbb
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting errors when the source file comes in `g++` command-line after the `-ltbb`, i.e. after much simplifying:

```
# Linker errors
g++ -ltbb program.cpp
# Works
g++ program.cpp -ltbb
```